# sub menu button click only reliably works in Test Runner

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

I am consistently getting a failure (test passes, the submission resulting from click step does not occur to be more accurate) running from CLI (headless or not) for a button click that works from the Cypress UI/Test Runner (./node_modules/.bin/cypress open). The element is a button that is available once an initial Save button is clicked. When I run from CLI, I see that the button is highlighted, but the click which would submit the page does not occur. Within the Cypress UI, the same code is resulting in a successful click & page submission. The code is:

```
saveOrder() {
    cy.get('button[data-test="saveOrderButton"]').eq(0).click();
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.get('button').contains('Save and View').click({ force: true, delay: 10000, timeout: 330000 });
}
```

I've tried adding additional waits after the second click. I have tried .dblclick(). Have also tried the jQuery click I found suggested elsewhere:

```
    cy.get('button').contains('Save and View').then(option => {
    cy.wrap(option).contains('Save and View');
    option[0].click();
})
```

Lastly, have also tried adding .trigger('mouseover') or .trigger('mousemove'). None of these efforts have allowed the test to work (button clicked) when run from CLI. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[this is what happens instead of a click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mUyC.png) (the button is highlighted but does not get clicked to submit).

[here is the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QIAW.png)

EDIT - I have gotten occasional CLI successes using the following code, but still very unreliable. The Test Runner results continue to pass every time. I thought the problem seemed to be the race condition discussed at https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click & perhaps I have mis-implemented the 3rd party plug-in, but I still have a very flaky test with the following:

```
   saveOrder() {
        cy.get('button[data-test="saveOrderButton"]').eq(0).click({ force: true, delay: 600, timeout: 330000 });
        cy.wait(5000);

        let count = 0
        const clickSaveView = $el => {
            count += 1
            return $el.click()
        }

        cy.contains('button', 'Save and View').eq(0)
            .should('be.visible')
            .wait(35000)
            .pipe(clickSaveView)
            .wait(5000)
            .should($el => {
                expect($el).to.not.be.visible
            })
            .then(() => {
                cy.log(`clicked ${count} times`)
            })
    }
```

When it passes, I see log writes that it clicked 5 times or 9 times or however many. When it mostly fails, I see that the element was still visible & the click submission didn't occur (error is "AssertionError: expected '<button.dropdown-item>' not to be 'visible'"). Is it reasonable to believe Test Runner can so easily await the listeners being attached while the application when Cypress is launched from CLI is incredibly slower? Is there some unadvertised limit of click attempts (or again have I maybe not implemented the .pipe(click) correctly)? I have tried sprinkling in waits every step of the way (which I thought cypress-pipe would eliminate the need for) but still haven't landed on a good solution.

Comment: Can you show what kind of error does the headless run give you? 

Also I suggest you try 

npx cypress run --browser chrome --headless

Comment: The test passes, the button just did not get clicked. I added the npx to the CLI call but got same outcome.

npx ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome --spec "cypress/integration/my_tests/new_order_entry_tests.js"

Comment: I would suggest to try .should('be.visible').click()  instead of waiting before the click, since it seeems like it depends on the rendering of the dome after the first click and Api response can`t be 100 % timed out. 

I had cases where the first click triggers change of the dome state and refresh, and the second click happens before the dome reload occurs. If this is the case - I would put on the first button .click().should('not.be.visible') and on the second button .should('be.visible').click()

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I added a link to an image of the situation. the commands to click succeed but the submission of the page does not occur. I added the .should('be.visible').click() you suggested but see the same outcome. (the first button will remain visible as in image, so did not add the should not be visible for that one). the perplexing aspect to me is that it succeeds when launched from the Cypress UI but not through any CLI attempts. I have updated to latest Chrome browser as well.

Comment: It seems possible that the element is not a button. Try using cy.contains('Save and View').should('be.visible').click(), or if it is a button cy.contains('button', 'Save and View').should('be.visible').click()

Comment: I tried each of those but with same outcome. I added a link to image of the DOM in the post now. It seems to understand & chose the target button properly, the click just does not fire the page submission for some reason.

Comment: Is it possible that you are running tests in diff browsers with Test runner and CLI ? Eg. For Test Runner its Chrome and for CLI its Electron ?

Comment: They both show to be using Chrome 86.

Comment: I have found many different ways to achieve the click & resulting submission call that work consistently in the Test Runner. I have seen a couple times now where various ones will work from CLI as well, but not with any consistency whatsoever. I am checking out the cypress-pipe plugin mentioned here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click. Thanks for all of the suggestions, they've definitely helped me dig in & gain a better understanding. Will loop back with outcome once I have tried out the plugin.

Comment: I updated the original post, but situation is I am seeing some CLI successes with cypress-pipe but mostly the same outcome (Test Runner passes every time while tests invoked by CLI are failing more than they pass). I have tried massaging timing but haven't come across anything that is reliable yet.